# "it is rusted" or "it has rusted" or "it has been rusted"?

Tags: grammar, active-vs-passive

Are they correct? or what are differences among these sentenses? 
  it is rusted.
  it has rusted.
  it has been rusted.

Answer (score 0):

The *phrase* 'It is rusted' (or 'rusty') means that something has rust on its surface.

'It has rusted' = it has developed rust on its surface (so the general meaning is much the same).

'It has been rusted' *could* mean that something was formerly rusty but has since been cleaned.